# What's the answer to this iq question

Tags: mathematics

Had a good thing about this question and haven't been able to come up with an answer. Any ideas?
[image]

Comment: This one looks even more obvious than the previous one...

Comment: I'm starting to think this is an attempt to advertise the app being shown.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is

> 6

For every box,

> The top row forms a two-digit number, which is the multiplication result of the bottom two independent digits.
>
>  42 = 7 x ? → ? = 6